# Value from parse method to pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following pipeline and simple spider, is there a way to get the `file_name` from the parse method of spider to the pipeline?

```
import csv,datetime
class AaexampleSpider(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.current_date = now.strftime("%d%b")
        self.file_name = file_name #file_name
        self.infile = open("{}_{}.csv".format(self.current_date, self.file_name),"w")
        self.dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(self.infile, fieldnames=["Hello"])
        self.dict_writer.writeheader()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.dict_writer.writerow(item)

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.infile.close()
```

spider code :

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        file_name = response.xpath('//div/h1/text()').extract_first()
        #code
```

if that is not possible, how can I use another spider to pass the value to the pipeline? I run the code using `scrapy crawl example` in terminal

Comment: I don't really see this working the way you've set it up. The pipeline will be created before the `parse` method does anything so I don't think you'll be able to use any extracted data from the spider's run in the pipeline's `__init__`.

Comment: @pwinz that is what I figured, how can I use another simple spider (before the main one) to do this